Soil texture triangle won't draw
My soil texture triangle drawn from USDA data works outside of shiny but not inside, I am simply trying to get it to draw "base" here. It's not even reactive yet. Do you have any tips why I am getting an error:

Warning: Error in FUN: invalid 'type' (character) of argument.

The error seems to be happening when I move the code from outside shiny to inside shiny. I already made sure my packages weren't interacting.
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(shinythemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(aqp)
library(soilDB)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(latticeExtra)
library(reshape2)
library(sjPlot)
library(bslib)
library(ggtern)
library(grid)


# Define the UI for the app
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("flatly"),
  titlePanel("Soil"),
  
  # Create the tabset panel
  tabsetPanel(
    
    tabPanel("Soil", 
             h3("Soil  Figures"),
             column(6, 
                    card(plotOutput("plot3"),
                         textOutput("plot3_caption")
                         
                    )
             )
    )
  )
  
  
)

# Define the server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    
    # Put tile labels at the midpoint of each tile using dplyr instead of plyr
    USDA.LAB <- USDA %>%
      dplyr::group_by(Label) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(
        Clay = mean(Clay),
        Sand = mean(Sand),
        Silt = mean(Silt)
      )
    
    # Tweak
    USDA.LAB$Angle = 0
    USDA.LAB$Angle[which(USDA.LAB$Label == 'Loamy Sand')] = -35
    
    # Custom 12 colors palette
    custom_colors <- c(
      "#E5C4A1", 
      "#D47D35", # (Warm Orange)
      "#C0C0C0", #(Light Gray)
      "#9F7F4E", #(Earthy Brown)
      "#6A7F67", #(Muted Green)
      "#E2D9A7", #(Pastel Yellow)
      "#9D62A0", #(Lavender Purple)
      "#B67E5D", #(Dusty Coral)
      "#A9D6A1",#(Mint Green)
      "#D1A6D8", #(Pastel Pink)
      "#D4B97B", #(Golden Yellow)
      "#3E6E58" #(Dark Green)
    )
    
    # Construct the plot
    base <-  ggplot(data = USDA, aes(y=Clay, x=Sand, z=Silt)) +
      coord_tern(L="x",T="y",R="z") +
      geom_polygon(alpha = 0.75, size = 0.5, color = 'black',
                   aes(color=Label, fill=Label)) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = custom_colors) +   # Custom colors for fill
      scale_color_manual(values = custom_colors) +  # Custom colors for borders
      geom_text(data = USDA.LAB,
                aes(label = Label, angle = Angle),
                color = 'black',
                size = 3.5) +
      theme_rgbw() +
      theme_showsecondary() +
      theme_showarrows() +
      custom_percent("Percent") +
      theme(legend.justification = c(0, 1),
            legend.position      = c(0, 1),
            axis.tern.padding    = unit(0.15, 'npc')) +
      labs(title = 'USDA Textural Classification Chart',
           fill  = 'Textural Class',
           color = 'Textural Class')
    
    
    base 
    
    
  })
  
  output$plot3_caption <- renderText({
    "The plot above shows..."
  })
  
  
  
  
  
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Welcome to SO!  The first thing I think of wehen I see a question like this is "Does it work if I don't use plotly?  Then I ask the OP to remove everything that isn't related to the error.  Here, that would be the formatting, the plotly theme, etc.  remove them one by one.  If the problem goes away, the thing you've just removed is the likely culprit.  Finally, not all of us have all the specialist packages you reference and may not want to install them simply to help you.  Your question would be more easily reprodicuble if you provided us with (a sample of) your dataset.

I am a soil science enthousiam and new to Shiny; but I don't see the definition for USDA .

I think there may be a problem with coord_tern(). I can get something with base <-  ggtern(data = USDA, aes(y=Clay, x=Sand, z=Silt)) etc.. while omitteing coord_tern()  but it doesn't look great.

Constructing  the plot base with the example in found with ?ggtern::data_USDA seems to work,  I will take a look to the differences .  (Also, I found the USDA, it's a dataset from ggtern )

I can't fully explain why, but thanks to this issue reffering to this one , you need to print() explicitely your ggplot element by changing  base with print(base) .  It's seem to be an easy workaround. Those issues are old (2016-2018), I don't understand why it happen nowadays.
Edit: This question seems to be a duplicate of this one, with a similar answer.

That works, thank you!
